# Reduced row echelon form and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Let's say I have the set of vectors $S = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ where $v_j \in R^m$, $v_j = (a_{1j}, a_{2j}, ..., a_{mj})$.

If the matrix formed by each of the vectors $A=[v_1, v_2, ..., v_n]$ looks like this (I believe), which is **not a square matrix**:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Then does A's reduced row echelon form help me determine whether the vectors of $S$ are linear dependent or independent? If so, how?**

I hope I got all the indices, notation and terminology right, since I am a beginner in linear algebra, and English is not my native language.

Comment: You have supplied the matrix $A$ with *columns* that correspond to vectors in $S$.  While the row echelon form of $A$ (reduced or not) does convey some information about the number of linearly independent vectors in $S$, it could create a more direct correspondence to have *rows* of $A$ taken from $S$.

Comment: @hardmath:
Yes, I have seen something similar somewhere else, where you put the vectors as columns of the matrix. How do you deduce from this the number of independent vectors? Also, how would you deduce the dependence/independence from the matrix of which the vectors are rows?

Comment: Old thread, but in fact putting the vectors in as *columns* and then computing reduced row echelon form gives you *more* insight about linear dependence than if you put them in as rows. The key thing is that ERO's preserve linear relations between the columns. So, you can row reduce, look at the corresponding columns, and typically tell at a glance not only if they were linearly independent (if so they'll all be pivot columns) but also in the case that they're dependent you'll be able to deduce dependence relations (since non-pivot columns are "diagonally" related to pivot columns).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "row rank" of $A$ is the number of linearly independent rows it has, and the "column rank" the number of its linearly independent columns.  The key facts are (for any matrix $A$) that:

- The row rank is equal to the column rank.
- The row (equiv. column) rank is unchanged by elementary row operations.

Therefore you can get the rank of $A$ (as we say for simplicity) by counting the leading ones of its row echelon form.  Since $S$ has $n$ vectors, we need the rank of $A$ to be $n$ (it cannot be more) in order for $S$ to be a linearly independent set.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I think I understand now.

Comment: I like to think of the reduced row-echelon form as the Swiss Army Knife of matrix computations, since it allows us to answer so many problems in linear algebra.

Comment: It does seem quite useful. That's why I asked this question: even though I wasn't sure you can use it for this purpose, it looked like it is connected. I just wasn't sure if and how.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, but since you are considering the column vectors, you know that they are all independent if each column has a leading one in the reduced row-echelon form.

If we look at an explicit example:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
    4       & 1 & 7 & 11 \\
    0       & 4 & -4 & -4 \\
    2       & 0 & 4 & 6 
\end{bmatrix}$

Then we have

$RREF(A)=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
    0       & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$

Notice that since columns $3$ and $4$ in $RREF(A)$ do not have leading $1$'s, they are dependent on the first two columns. Specifically:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    -1        \\
   7 \\
-4 \\
4
\end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}
    1        \\
   4 \\
0 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
    3        \\
   1 \\
4 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
    0        \\
   11 \\
-4 \\
6
\end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix}
    1        \\
   4 \\
0 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
    3        \\
   1 \\
4 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

Notice that the entries in column $3$ of $RREF(A)$ respectively correspond to the scalars for columns $1$ and $2$, such that column $3$ can be written as a linear combination of those columns. And the same goes for column $4$.

But if each column of $RREF(A)$ has a leading $1$, then each column is linearly independent.

Sidenote: The number of rows with all zeros in $RREF(A)$ tell only how many rows are independent/dependent (unless it is a square matrix, then the number of (in)dependent rows/columns will be the same) Looking at the leading 1's is much more helpful in determining linear dependence.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! I think I got it!

Comment: For your explanation on how you find the coefficients of the dependent columns,  $(2, -1)$ and $(3, -1)$, these are the coefficient of the first and second independent column (the ones with the pivots), not the first and second in the matrix, from what I believe. Is this true? For your example they are the same, but for $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\ \end{pmatrix}$ I believe these will be different and the coefficients will be for the independent pivot columns, if I understand correctly.

Comment: No, it actually would still work. For $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 2 && 4 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 3 \end{bmatrix}$$, we have $$RREF(A)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 && 0 && -2 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 3 \end{bmatrix}$$. Then we would have $$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}=-2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+3\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I may not have worded it clearly, but the coefficient in that row for each dependent column corresponds to the independent column whose pivot is in that row.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you can convert the matrix into reduced row echelon form(or even just row echelon form) without a row of $0$s,then the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: Does this work the other way around? Can you say that if you cannot convert the matrix into reduced row echelon form without a row of $0s$, the vectors are linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes. That is true also.

Comment: Well, let's say I have the vectors $(1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)$. They are clearly independent. The reduced row echelon form would be $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, if I haven't made any mistakes. It has a row of $0s$, yet it the vectors are linearly independent. Am I mistaking/missing something?

Comment: @hardmath Good point.  I assumed the OP was talking about square matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, guys :) I got it.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Comment: @Tim: "without a row of 0s" should be "with a leading one in each column".