# Check if the following vectors are linearly independent or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Check whether the following rows are linearly dependent/independent:
>   \begin{aligned}(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),\\
>  (1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),\\
>  (1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0),\\
>  (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0),\\
>  (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0),\\
>  (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-3).\end{aligned}
>
> If linearly dependent find the relation between them.

I tried to do using the combination $$c_1(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)+c_2(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0)+c_3(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0)\\+c_4(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0)+c_5 (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)+c_6 (1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,-3)\\=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$$

and I got $c_1=3c_6, \;c_2=c_3=c_4=c_5=0.$

But $c_1-3c_6\neq 0.$

So where am I wrong? Please help.

Comment: I think for $c_6=1$ and $c_1=3$ you get what you need

Comment: @PureMathematics Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Subtract every row (but the first) from the first.

$(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,4)$

Then subtract row $2$ to $5$ from $6$.

$(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)$

...

$(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
\\(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)$

This should be convincing enough. (As José did, you can dispense yourself with the first four columns.)

Answer (score 0):

Let put the vectors as rows in a matrix and check for the RREF. From the number of pivots we can deduce whether or not the vectors are linearly independent.

Refer also to [Reduced row echelon form and linear independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1624238/505767)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got $c_1-3c_6=0$. The vectors are linearly independent. For instance if you forget the first $4$ coordinates of each vector and you obtain a $6\times6$ matrix from the rest, then that matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3\end{bmatrix},$$whose determinant is $1\neq0$.