# Given an original matrix A and RREF R, how to determine the linear combination of independent columns to use to obtain dependent columns of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Background**

I have a large matrix that I need to determine (a) which columns are independent and which are dependent, and (b) what operations to perform to obtain the dependent columns from the independent ones. The first part is easy, as I can just calculate the reduced row echelon form (RREF) of the matrix. Then, I can easily tell which columns are pivot columns as those that have a leading one in a new row. I am stuck though, when I try to figure out what operations to perform to obtain the dependent columns from the independent ones.

I saw what I thought was the answer in the top rated answer by yung_Pabs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624238/reduced-row-echelon-form-and-linear-independence) on StackExchange. He/she writes, "Notice that the entries in column 3 of () respectively correspond to the scalars for columns 1 and 2, such that column 3 can be written as a linear combination of those columns. And the same goes for column 4." I can see that this is indeed the case for this matrix. However, when I tried it on my large matrix, this did not work. (Actually, it worked for the first dependent column, but other dependent columns are not correct.) Here is a link to the MATLAB code containing the large matrix and what I have tried in MATLAB so far.
https://pastebin.com/Mq7u7UBZ

**tl;dr:**
For each entry j in a nonpivot column i of a rref matrix, I multiplied entry j by the columns of the original matrix A. I expected to get back column i. However, I got back a column that was not column i. Why is this the case?

Edit: I wrote up this question and then figured it out right before I posted it. But because I spent 8 hours trying to figure out the answer and couldn't find the answer on StackOverflow or discussions with chatGPT, I'm going to still post the question and answer in the hopes it helps someone else in the future

Comment: ChatGPT is a terribly, terribly bad resource for math questions. Do yourself a favor and do not use it for that. Its tone of complete certainty only rivals the intensity of the nonsense it produces. Be the intelligent part in the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is that the entries in the i'th column of RREF(A) give the coefficients for the *independent* columns only. Dependent (nonpivot) columns should be skipped over. When I update my MATLAB code to use entries as coefficients for *only the independent* columns, the original dependent column is properly obtained. (Updated MATLAB: https://pastebin.com/HfynyFvZ )