# Finding linearly independent subset of rows

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I have a matrix $B$ of size $m$-by-$n$, where $m \gg n$. I would like to pick $m$ linearly independent rows from it and use those to form a matrix that is guaranteed to have an inverse.

I am struggling to figure out how to find these rows.

[Another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624238/reduced-row-echelon-form-and-linear-independence) seems to imply that, in reduced row echelon form, any row of $RREF(B)$ with a leading 1 implies the same row of $B$ is linearly independent from the others in $B$, but this couldn't possibly be true, since row $RREF_i(B)$ captures information about potentially many rows of $B$, and it's not necessarily true that the independence comes from $B_i$.

How might I find a linearly independent subset from the rows of $B$?

Comment: You should instead look at the RREF of $B^\top$, not $B$.

Comment: If $m>n$, you won't be able to find $m$ linearly independent rows.